# Скобки у модуля

Tags: javascript, ооп

Я понимаю зачем нужен модуль и вобще зачем нужна инкапсуляция. Однако никак не могу понять чем обусловлен его синтаксис `(function(){ код })()`.

Откуда берутся и что делают скобки вокруг функции?

Зачем и как мы вызываем анонимную функцию (как я понимаю именно это делают круглые скобки сразу после {})?

Почему при создании библиотек (например для jQuery) мы пишем `(function(){ код })(jQuery)`?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77430/discussion-on-question-by-brachkoff---).

Comment: Кстати, хороший вопрос

Comment: Ну и зачем вы переоткрыли вопрос? Там третий дубликат (который я повторно предложил) - был точный же!

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо, сейчас отмечу

Answer (score 2):

IIFE можно вызвать разными способами.
Сложилось так, что обычно IIFE обёртывают в скобки; это необходимо чтобы явно дать понять синтаксическому анализатору что тут будет выражение, а не объявление функции.
Иначе, встретив `function`, начнётся разбор объявления:

```
(function () { /* ... */ })();
(function () { /* ... */ }());
(() => { /* ... */ })(); // В стрелочных функциях скобки разрешены только снаружи
```

Хотя скобки не обязательны, эти варианты так же работают:

```
!function () { /* ... */ }();
~function () { /* ... */ }();
-function () { /* ... */ }();
+function () { /* ... */ }();
void function () { /* ... */ }();
```

Если из контекста ясно что тут должно быть именно выражение, явно указывать уже не требуется:

```
var f = function () { /* ... */ }();
true && function () { /* ... */ }();
0, function () { /* ... */ }();
```

<sub>[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)</sub>

Comment: А зачем она вызывается сразу?

Comment: В смысле? А зачем вообще модуль? Почитайте тогда дубли, если не знаете.

Comment: Дубли? Что это?

Comment: Ваш вопрос закрыли как дубликат. И показали что дубликат чего именно. Вот по тем ссылкам почитайте.

Comment: Ни один из дубликатов не отвечает на вопросы указаные в вопросе

Comment: @brachkoff Возможно. Но ответ я Вам уже дал, остальные вопросы можно предвосхитить чтением предложенных ссылок.